# ASP.NET Membership Get how many times user failed to login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

My web.config allow max 10 fail passwords attempts. But i want to add recaptcha after 5 fails.

How i can get number of failed attempts with membership or even with custom function?

Answer (score 3):

This resource here http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-asp-net-2-0-security-membership-role-management-isbn-978-0-7645-9698-8/39682-failed-login-attempts-counts.html states that it cannot be done directly through the api and must be done via a separate sql call. Quote from article below:

> We don't expose this information directly in the API. However, you can
>   query the database and select the user's row from the
>   vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers view. Then look at the
>   FailedPasswordAttemptCount column to get the current number of failed
>   attempts.
>
> -Stefan
>   Author: Professional ASP.NET 2.0 Security, Membership, and Role Management

Comment: thats stupid since i want to implement captcha on > max/2 failed attemps... i done this with session counter...but looke like i need to make custom query or use another database table...